# Ansible synchronize with private key

Tags: ansible

I want to use the ansible module synchronize with using a private_key.

When issuing the following command, everything works fine:

```
localuser$ rsync -rltDvzu --delete -e ssh . remoteuser@rsync.cloud.com:/users/remoteuser/
```

Here is my playbook the achieve the same, executing as root:

```
- name: Synchronization of src on the control machine to dest on the remote hosts
  synchronize:
    src: /raid5/Pictures/
    dest: rsync://remoteuser@rsync.cloud.com:/users/remoteuser/
    recursive: yes
    private_key: /home/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa
    set_remote_user: no
    copy_links: no
    times: yes
    checksum: yes
    rsync_opts: -e "ssh"
```

Doing this, the password prompt shows up.

I've tried the following:

- toggling set_remote_user --> Password prompt shows up
- set_fact, ansible_user to localuser or remoteuser --> Password prompt shows up
- extending rsync_opts with -i and the path to my private key --> Error message: No such file or directory

**UPDATE TO THE PLAYBOOK**

```
become: yes
become_user: localuser
```

still the password prompt shows up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in the first case, you are not root, and in the second, you are. So the ssh bi-key used is not the same in this 2 cases, is it ?